# Excel Merge data columns

Tags: excel-2007

i am trying to merge excel columns into one column like this...

```
List1   List2   List3   List4   List5
1       0       0       0       0
0       1       0       0       0
0       0       1       0       0
0       0       0       1       0
0       0       0       0       1
```

into this...

```
List
0
1
2
3
4
```

If there is a 1 in List1 the merged column will have value 0
if List2 is a 1 the merged column will have value 1
and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data start in top-left corner, then for the cells in the result range you could write array formulas like

```
{=SUM(A2:E2*(COLUMN(A2:E2)-1))}
```

Another idea is to write a single array formula for the whole result range

```
{=MMULT(A2:E6,{0;1;2;3;4})}
```

Comment: both of the formulas gives me format error's.

I wrote a C# console app reading and writing from text files to solve the problem tho... but that's not a solution for this question which is how to achieve this in excel...

Comment: @furier Maybe you'll have better luck copying these formulas from a google docs spreadsheet at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtxtEpptxPJsdHZwWmh1eS1OVlQxTHo5S1liLXdnRGc